# Custom Java map deserialzer in Gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

Is it possible to convert an array of object pairs into a `Map`, by selecting values from each pair, without creating an intermediate POJO?

For example, say that there are 2 `Java` classes (`Key.class`, `Value.class`) and a `JSON` array constructed from serialized pairs of their objects, as follows

```
[
  {"key":{}, "value":{}}, // Objects k1, v1
  {"key":{}, "value":{}}, // Objects k2, v2
  {"key":{}, "value":{}}, // Objects k3, v3
  {"key":{}, "value":{}}, // Objects k4, v4
]
```

Can `Gson` "directly" (i.e., without a POJO definition) deserialize the above array into a `Map`, in which the actual keys and values are populated from a manipulation of the corresponding `Key` and `Value` objects, instead of the "full" objects?

In other words, given two `Java` types `K` and `V` that may be different to `Key` and `Value`, the deserialization per pair should be

```
(k1:Key, v1:Value) --> (k1':K, v1':V)
```

where

```
k1' = function(k1)
v1' = function(v1)
```

A custom adapter like this does not work:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Type type = (new TypeToken<Map<K, V>>() {}).getType();    
builder.registerTypeAdapter(type, new JsonDeserializer<Map<Key, Value>>() {
  @Override
  public Map<K, V> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    // Custom deserialization block,
    // invoking the `function()` method
  }
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

Using the above adapter results in `Gson` passing the entire array to the `deserialize()` method, where it has to be manipulated manually, which is both tedious and error-prone.

With a custom `POJO` like

```
public class KeyValue {
  Key k;
  Value v;
}
```

the above `JSON` array can be deserialized into an array or set of `KeyValue` objects, which can then be converted to a `Map<K, V>`. But could the same be done without the `KeyValue` POJO;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid having the POJO class you refer to as `KeyValue` I think the only way to do that with gson is to create an adapter. The reason being that your JSON does not conform to any generic, built-in class and therefore gson is not going to be able to understand it without having the custom logic to do so.

Since you have the `Key` and `Value` classes you can take advantage of that inside of your custom adapter. I think you will find that this reduces the tediousness of the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Type type = (new TypeToken<Map<Key, Value>>() {}).getType();    
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(type, new JsonDeserializer<Map<Key, Value>>() {
          @Override
          public Map<Key, Value> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
              Map<Key, Value> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
              JsonArray jArr = json.getAsJsonArray();
              for(int i=0; i < jArr.size(); i++){
                  JsonObject item = jArr.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                  processKeyValue(item, resultMap);
              }
              return resultMap;
          }

          private void processKeyValue(JsonObject mapEntry, Map<Key, Value> resultMap){
              Gson gson = new Gson();
              Key key = gson.fromJson(mapEntry.get("key"), Key.class);
              Value value = gson.fromJson(mapEntry.get("value"), Value.class);
              resultMap.put(key, value);
          }
        });
        Gson gson = builder.create();

        //Note: assume that the variable "json" is a JSON string. I removed my code for getting the string since I'm just reading from a file and I don't know how you're getting your data.

        // Deserialization

        Map<Key,Value> outputMap = gson.fromJson(json, type);


        System.out.println("RESULTS: "+outputMap.toString());
    }
```

I used your example data, but slightly modified to have a little more content. I created two very simple POJO classes for `Key` and `Value` - they only have a `String` field named `id`, a getter and setter for that field, and a `toString` method.

This was the input I used when running the above code:

```
[
  {"key":{"id":"k1"}, "value":{"id":"v1"}}, 
  {"key":{"id":"k2"}, "value":{"id":"v2"}},
  {"key":{"id":"k3"}, "value":{"id":"v3"}}, 
  {"key":{"id":"k4"}, "value":{"id":"v4"}}
]
```

The output is:

```
RESULTS: {Key [id=k2]=Value [id=v2], Key [id=k1]=Value [id=v1], Key [id=k3]=Value [id=v3], Key [id=k4]=Value [id=v4]}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the only approach. Thanks.